# Show Hide on Radio Button Clicked

Tags: jquery

I have 7 radio buttons on many rows (rows are dynamic) and I am trying to achieve two things.

1. On radio button hover -- show/hide div and when it is clicked keep the div (pin it). I have managed to show hide on hover and on click pin the hidden div. However, it fails when I click the radio buttons of the same row.
2. Pending radio button is checked by default on page load. If a user does not change from pending to other radio buttons or after changing comes back to pending (if all the radio buttons are pending), then an alert needs to show saying ("No records have been change").

I don't even mind if we do any other way. We use Jquery version 1.6 and support IE 8. We do not need to use data() can use hasClass which I tried.

```
 $(".r-title").hide();
 $("input:radio").hover(function() {
if(!$(this).hasClass('pinned'))
$(this).prev('.r-title').toggle();
 });
```

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/jj4Uv/7/)**

```
$(".r-title").hide();
 $("input:radio").hover(function() {
if(!$(this).data('pinned'))
$(this).prev('.r-title').toggle();
 });

 $("input:radio").click(function () {
var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
 $(this).data('pinned',$("r-title").show());    
 });
```

Comment: 1) What you say "it fails", what does? 2) What have you tried?

Comment: What I mean is the previous radio buttons' div remain if I click on other radio buttons of the same row. Please click on few radio buttons of one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few remarks regarding your code:

First, there is no point in making all `r-title` visible and then hiding them on load. You should hide them by default with css `display: none`.

Also, you need to hide `r-title` every time you click the radio button. On click hide all `r-title` of the same row and show only the one associated with radio button.

Create a function that will display text of the selected radios on load (or do it server side with whatever you generate your page with).

Everything I pointed out you can see at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/10/

Also, make sure you wrap the script in onLoad event (or `$(document).ready()`).

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We are using DHTMLX Grid and your advice is highly appreciated. Any chance of looking at the alert (point 2)

Comment: I noticed the last radio you clicked the hover doesnt work for. Say you hover then click on OK and the last clicked one was Fair. The hover for Fair does not work. Then if you click fair OK doesnt work. I dont see why that is.

Comment: @19eggs you already have the counter, it's only a matter of adding `if (counter==0) alert();`. Right?

Comment: Don't worry about that..;o)) I will sort it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/jj4Uv/11/

```
$("input:radio").hover(function() {
    $(this).prev('.r-title').show();
}, function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prev('.r-title').hide();
    }
});
$("input:radio").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title').hide()
    var totalRd = $('table').find(':not(.pend) > input:radio:checked').length;
    $("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);
    $(this).prev('.r-title').show();  
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. Any solution to Point Number 2..the alert...